# GraphQL Server unreachable

Tags: graphql, azure-functions

I am trying to create serverless azure function with graphql in visualstudio code. I am following the below tutorial

[Build Serverless API with GraphQL and Azure— Part I](https://itnext.io/build-serverless-api-with-graphql-and-azure-part-i-e9e7f4be0200)

After starting the application, i see the error attached in the browser. unable to execute query because of the error.

[image]

Tried with the embed sandbox on your own website . In step 4(in the attached image below) it is mentioned as copy paste the code to HTML. I don't have any html in my code. Not sure how to solve this

[image]

My project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same with below code in my environment, and got the same error:***

**Code Snippet:**

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-azure-functions');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!',
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();
```

**Response:**

[image]

***Later, Tried with the below code taken from [Official Document](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v3/deployment/azure-functions/), and it worked without any issues:***

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } =  require('apollo-server-azure-functions');

const { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } =  require('apollo-server-core');

const  typeDefs  =  gql`
    type Query {
    hello: String
    }
`;

const  resolvers  = {
        Query: {
            hello: () =>  'Hello world!',
               },

};

const  server  =  new  ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, csrfPrevention:  true, cache:  'bounded',plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed:  true }),],});

exports.graphqlHandler  =  server.createHandler();
```

**Response:**

[image]

[image]